# Conditially override scss variables for bootstrap 4 theme switching

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, webpack, sass, create-react-app

Per the [Bootstrap docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/theming/#variable-defaults),

> Every Sass variable in Bootstrap 4 includes the !default flag allowing
>   you to override the variable’s default value in your own Sass without
>   modifying Bootstrap’s source code. Copy and paste variables as needed,
>   modify their values, and remove the !default flag. If a variable has
>   already been assigned, then it won’t be re-assigned by the default
>   values in Bootstrap.

So they recommend you create your own theme like this:

```
// Your variable overrides
$body-bg: #000;
$body-color: #111;

// Bootstrap and its default variables
@import "node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";
```

What I would like to do is have two sets of variables, and uses this to switch between a light and dark theme:

```
// Your variable overrides
body.light-mode {
  $body-bg: #fff;
}
body.dark-mode {
  $body-bg: #000;
}
// Bootstrap and its default variables
@import "node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";
```

But this doesn't seem to be working, I think because of how variables are scoped.

Is this possible? Ideally I'd like to have light and dark variables in their own file.

For a little context; I am using bootstrap in a web app created by create-react-app, and they recommend to import bootstrap as [detailed here](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-bootstrap/). If I just generated 2 separate style sheets I'd have copy those to my /public folder manually and reference, and they wouldn't be part of the webpack bundling.

Comment: You try to overrides variables that you import at the end of your scss file. So actually this bootstrap scss file will overrides the variables that you wrote before. Try to first import the file and then overrides the variables.

Comment: This is a method to create dark-light themes with sass: => https://medium.com/@katiemctigue/how-to-create-a-dark-mode-in-sass-609f131a3995. It is a good method, on my personal opinion, maybe there are many others and maybe better than this, but this was for me a starting point. I hope this method helps you too :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This was the solution I went with:

```
// Default theme
$body-bg: #fff;
// etc...

// Bootstrap and its default variables
@import "node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";

// dark theme, turned on by adding class dark to document.documentElement (html tag)
.dark {
  $body-bg: #000;
  // etc...

  // Import just the things you customize 
  @import "~bootstrap/scss/functions";
  @import "~bootstrap/scss/variables";
  @import "~bootstrap/scss/mixins";

  @import "~bootstrap/scss/tables";
  @import "~bootstrap/scss/button-group"
  // etc....

}
```

Comment: Been looking for this for long time now. Controlling theme by class name is way more convenient than full CSS file replacement specially for selective customization of bootstrap sass components.

Answer (score 1):

That won't work. Why not make two different themes - dark/light:

light theme (light-theme.scss):

```
// Your variable overrides
$body-bg: #fff;

// Bootstrap and its default variables
@import "node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";
```

dark theme (dark-theme.scss):

```
// Your variable overrides
$body-bg: #000;

// Bootstrap and its default variables
@import "node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";
```

and then pull the appropriate style sheet into the page as needed?

Comment: That's an option, but I am using create-react-app which uses webpack; they recommend bringing in bootstrap through a js import. So doing it that way breaks it out of their whole webpack bundling. I'll add this to my question.

Comment: This answer won't break your webpack bundling. Maintaining theme-specific variables in separated Sass files are good practice in Sass architecture design.